# Control + H Deletes text and other weird keyboard shortcuts

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, macos, shortcut

For some weird reason, when I hold down Control + H it deletes the text as if I was pressing the "Delete" button. Occasionally, when I hold down Control + L and have a text highlighted, it would highlight it in yellow as if I clicked hard enough to define it.

This just started happening a few days ago. I did not install any apps or programs prior to this happening. I tried this in Chrome, Notes, and other apps to see if it was app specific - it wasn't. It had this problem system wide. I also booted my Mac in safe mode and it still happens in safe mode.

Does anyone have any idea as to what's happening?

I have a 2015 Macbook Pro running on OS X High Sierra 10.13.3.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you expecting to happen when you press those shortcuts?

The two keyboard shortcuts you mention are standard MacOS. The behaviour you describe is normal.

https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201236

Are you confusing the Command and Control keys?

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know that was a shortcut. Is it possible to disable that shortcut?

Comment: @Edward why are you pressing them?

Comment: I'm using Better Touch Tool and CTRL + H,J,K,L is supposed to move the point. I've already had this setup for several months and this just started happening maybe a few days ago.

Comment: @Edward what do you mean "supposed to move the point"? CTRL+H/J/K/L should move the text caret/cursor or the mouse pointer? In BetterTouchTool do you have them set globally or for specific applications? Please edit the question with a screenshot of your BTT setup and information about your usage of these shortcut keys you have defined.

Comment: My bad, I meant in BTT, I have them set globally where CTRL+H/J/K/L does the same things as the "Left", "Up", "Down", "Right" arrow keys in the keyboard. So in a text box, I can move the text cursor left a few letters or right a few letters, etc...

Comment: @Edward OK, I have tried it in BTT and custom mappings override the standard macOS behaviour. I've just tried it on this comment. Are you sure BTT is running and active in all apps? Are you sure you have BTT set up correctly?

Comment: Yes, here are my settings: https://i.imgur.com/anBL2Br.png and here's the specific setting for just one of them (CTRL+H): https://i.imgur.com/mV7qN1j.png

Comment: I cannot reproduce. So I suggest posting a bug report/issue at https://github.com/fifafu/BetterTouchTool

Comment: I reformatted my computer due to another problem I was having with my Mac and that seemed to fix everything. Maybe a virus?

Comment: I don't think you can come to that conclusion. Best of luck to you. Maybe accept my answer?

Answer (score -2):

You can see, change or remove any of the keyboard shortcuts by going to System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts.

Comment: I don't see the shortcut in there